# ADF V1 - Calling a Stored Proc with Parameter based on SQL Query

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In ADF V1, in Sproc Activity, is there a way to supply a input parameter based on a SQL query? For example let's say there's a procedure dbo.testProc which expects a parameter param1 and I need to supply the param1 value by looking at a value in a table (select column1 from table_A). How can I specify this? I know in V2 we can use look up activity but in V1 there seems to be no way. Is it impossible in V1?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a wrapper-style Stored Proc, e.g.

a) looks up the value with a SELECT statement, stored in a @param1 variable

b) calls your dbo.testProc @param1